# Show that a sum of operators is bounded.

Tags: operator-theory

Let $T$ be an operator for wich there existe $M\geq 0$ such that :
$$ \|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T^k\|\leq M , \, \forall n\geq 1.$$

Show that for every $r$, $0<r<1$, $$ \|(1-r)\sum _{k\geq 0}r^kT^k\|\leq M.$$

I don't know how to proceed. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: If $n = 0$, the expression $\|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T^k\|\leq M$ is problematic!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\frac{1}{1-r}(I+rT+r^2T^2+\cdots)=I+r(I+T)+r^2(I+T+T^2)+\cdots+r^n(1+T+\cdots+T^n)+\cdots
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{1}{1-r}\left\|(I+rT+r^2T^2+\cdots)\right\|\le
\|I\|+r\|I+T\|+r^2\|I+T+T^2\|+\cdots+r^n\|1+T+\cdots+T^n\|+\cdots \le M+2rM+3r^2M+\cdot+(n+1)r^nM+\cdots=\frac{M}{(1-r)^2}.
$$